# HTML 5 browser geolocation don't work on desktop browsers

Tags: geolocation

Why HTML 5 browser geolocation don't work on some desktop(especially LAN or wired PC's).But when I use my laptop and mobile it can return a latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desktop computers don't usually have GPS receivers, cellular network connections, or connect using wireless Internet, which are the usual ways to get location information on mobile devices.

Comment: Before when my connection is broadband it is working.Though I don't have a GPS.